# How to Scale Globally After Rotating Locally?

Tags: modifiers, transforms

I want to be able to scale an object using something similar to the Mesh Deform modifier, however it applies the original object's rotation *before* it is scaled.

I've tried to visualise this by using a separate object per frame, but I'd want to have a single object that is deformed in this same way:

[image: Left: normal object, Right: squashed object]

Comment: Parent the object to an empty.  Scale the empty in one axis.  Rotate the object.  Does this do what you want?  I'm not sure I understand the question from the wording.

Comment: @Nathan Yep that actually worked, and is exactly what I was looking for, so thanks! I wasn't aware of the "order" of transformations for objects parented to each other so it never occured to me.